# What is procedure of doing vrata of thursday?

Tags: fasting, vrata

What is the procedure of doing Vrata of Thursday ?

What should we eat or not eat on thursday ?

Should we eat only fruits ?

Or should we give up only salt ?

Should we eat only once ?

Comment: Local Panjikas contain the information about procedures for various Vratas.